# Own Class For A Div Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use the following code, with my own class?

```
$('div').click(function(){
$(this).animate({height:'300'})
})
```

Forexample :

```
.changeheight{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
```

And how can i give it, an onclick link or button?

Comment: `$("div.changeheight")` or simply `$(".changeheight")`

Comment: how can i use it with a button or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... As stated in my comment `$("div.changeheight") or simply $(".changeheight")`

But you also had a question within your original question.

So if you want to fire this function, when clicking another element (button, div, whatever you want), instead of `$(this).doSomething()`, use `$(".myClass").doSomething()`

Example:

```js
$("#myButton").click(function(){
  $("div.changeheight").animate({height:'300'})
});
```

```css
.changeheight{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
margin: auto;
}

#myButton {
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changeheight">
</div>

<div id="myButton">Fire!!</div>
```

Hope it helped.
Cheers,

Comment: If it helped, please consider marking it the right answer, much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the selector in your jQuery call to match your CSS:

```
$('.changeheight').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'300'})
})
```